# How to use double database in Play Framework with Ebean

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, ebean

I'm brand new with `Play Framework` and with `Ebean`. I need to configure a Play application to use two different database instances, one for reading and another for writing. I have been looking in it seems that this is a recurrent issue and I've tried all the possible solutions that I've been able to find, even the once that works for somebody and isn't working for me, for sure I'm doing something wrong, because the error has to do or looks like with the `classloader`.

`build.sbt`

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
val playEbean = "6.0.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
"com.typesafe.play" % "play-ebean_2.13" % playEbean,
...
```

`application.conf`

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_writer"
db.default.username=username
db.default.password=pass

db.reader.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.reader.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_reader"
db.reader.username=username
db.reader.password=pass

ebean.default = ["models.db_writer.*"]
ebean.reader = ["models.db_reader.*"]

play.ebean.defaultDatasource = "db_writer"
```

`EbeanServerReader`

```
import io.ebean.Ebean;
import io.ebean.EbeanServer;

public class EbeanServerReader {

    public static EbeanServer getReader() {
        return Ebean.getServer("reader");
    }
}
```

`myDaoClass`

```
public class myDaoClass {

    private final FetchConfig fetchConfig = new FetchConfig();
    private final EbeanServer reader = EbeanServerReader.getReader();
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
 
      public PagedList<SomeClass> findAllWithNoLimit(int pageIndex, int pageSize, String type) {
        return reader.find(SomeClass.class)
                .fetch("path", fetchConfig.lazy(100))
                .fetch("path", fetchConfig.lazy(100))
                .fetch("path", fetchConfig.lazy(100))
                .where()
                .eq("propertyName", type)
                .order()
                .desc("updatedAt")
                .setFirstRow(pageIndex * pageSize)
                .setMaxRows(pageSize)
                .findPagedList();
    }
```

Error trace:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.ebean.Ebean
  at models.myDaoClass.<init>(myDaoClass.java:12)
  while locating models.myDaoClass
    for the 1st parameter of models.myDaoClass.<init>(myDaoClass.java:33)
  while locating models.myDaoClass

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1097)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1131)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:436)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:431)
    at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.$anonfun$instanceOf$2(Injector.scala:119)
    at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.withContext(Injector.scala:128)
    at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.instanceOf(Injector.scala:119)
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorRefProvider.$anonfun$get$1(Akka.scala:268)
    at akka.actor.TypedCreatorFunctionConsumer.produce(IndirectActorProducer.scala:91)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:226)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:613)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:640)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.ebean.Ebean
    at module.EbeanServerReader.getReader(EbeanServerReader.java:8)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've try another stuffs, like `@Inject` but is the same.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by replacing:

```
ebean.default = ["models.db_writer.*"]
ebean.reader = ["models.db_reader.*"]
```

with this:

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
ebean.writer = ["models.*"]
```

as my application uses the same `class model` just different `db` instances, one for reading and another for writing.